# Executing PHP Script Remotely From Another Server

Tags: php, cron, remote-access, remote-server

I have a PHP script on a server A that is executed by accessing the url `domain.com/dir/script.php`. I want to create a PHP script on server B that will execute that script on server A remotely. How do I do this?

Comment: Use `cURL` or `file_get_contents($url)`

Comment: @Barmar and he will need probably a cron job, if he want's to run in on schedule

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `file_get_contents` to access a URL in PHP:

```
$results = file_get_contents('http://domain.com/dir/script.php');
```

Comment: will that execute script.php on server A or server B? Since it is only getting contents of script.php, does that mean it will execute the script on Server B. I would like to run script.php on server A, but trigger the script from server B.

Comment: It runs on server A. It's not getting the contents of the script, it's performing an HTTP request for the URL, just like a browser does. The "contents" that it gets are whatever the webserver returns when you access the URL.